# Why is my implementation of the RSA algorithm in Python very slow?

Tags: python, rsa

I recently made a Python application of the RSA algorithm, but it starts to become seriously slow when I use numbers that are very big.

```
from math import *

def findkeys(p,q):
    n = p*q
    tn = (p-1)*(q-1)
    e = 0
    for x in range(2,tn-1):
        if gcd(x,tn) == 1:
            e = x
    d = 0
    for x in range(2,tn-1):
        frm = (1+(x*tn))/e
        if float(int(frm)) == float(frm):
            d = int(frm)
    return e,d,n

def rsa(message,key,n):
    return (message**key)%n
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have some driver code, with numbers for which you feel the algorithm is too slow?

Comment: You need to learn a little more python, you don't seem to understand the difference between python integers and floats. But your speed issue can be solved by writing a more efficient modular exponentiation or just using python's: replace `return return (message**key)%n` with `return pow(message, key, n)`

Comment: @president-james-moveon-polk Hi, I do know the difference between floats and ints. The thing I did on line 13 is to check if the result (frm) is an integer and I didn't bother to look for the correct function to do so. And thank you I did not know of the pow function.

Comment: Ok, then don't use floats for RSA. Anywhere. Only use ints. That also means stop using float division ("/"). Use only integer division ("//").

Comment: @president-james-moveon-polk But if I do that I will always get an int as a result to frm but I need to know if the result of the division is an int.

Comment: a / b is an int if and only if a % b == 0. You never need floats in RSA. Never.